# How do I Eliminate render-blocking resources for my wp website please?

Tags: contentful, render-blocking

My site is really slow and it says its because of a large contentful paint2.2s. can anyone help please.  I have no knowledge of programming but have built my site using wp and youtube help videos, but they all want to use wp rocket which i find its depracted so would rather not use it. Also I have got this error today and ive tried to fix it but can't.  cURL error 28: Connection timeout after 10000 ms